# VBA get value from ComboBox to hide row

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a little bit difficult in getting combobox value.
The properties of this combobox is already linked to "C10" cell. So I assumed the combobox value = C10 value.
The combobox values are supposed to be hide non-used row, if the value of C10 = CM or QM or QMC or CM

```
If Worksheets("QC Generator").Range("C10").Value = "QM,PM,QMC,CM" Then
Worksheets("page2").Rows("43").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
Worksheets("page2").Rows("43").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: what combobox type do you have: a `Form` one or an `ActiveX` one ?

Comment: its an ActiveX combobox

Answer (score 0):

Try using the filter method on an array of the values.

```
allowed = Array("QM", "PM", "QMC", "CM")

If UBound(Filter(allowed, Range("C10").Value)) > -1 Then
  Worksheets("page2").Rows("43").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
  Worksheets("page2").Rows("43").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

Comment: it really works! thank you captain

any way how if the combobox is literally not only "PM" "CM" "QMC" but it has their own types such as "PM-F" "PM-F-LV" "CM-S" and so....is it possible to detect by the most left words? or should I write down all possibilities ?

Comment: Depending on how the combo is populating you could set the array to use that range as the array source. If they can alter the types and create user defined values maybe look at storing the values somewhere and they checking the value entered against the stored list and if not there adding it.
Oh the left most part yeah, try Left(Range("C10").Value, 2).... Maybe change the 2 to a max of the result of a find of the value and "-" and the value of 2. That is off the top of my head and I would have to play with it to get it going. Have a go and see where you end up.

Comment: i already figured how, i made 2 combobox which is the 2nd one are correlated to the 1st one, and the 1st one is the key-word. thanks for your help!